# How to unit test the following methods?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unit-testing, uitextfield

I am adding the following code. I want to see examples of unit testing these. I am very new to this so any help would be great! Please provide code! Thanks

```
 //Dismiss keyboard when tapping on screen
func tapGesture(gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer){

    romanNumeralTextfield.resignFirstResponder()

}


//When return key is tapped the keyboard is dismissed
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    romanNumeralTextfield.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}


//Display keyboard
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
    }

}


//Hide keyboard
func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you can write a unit test for. Unit tests are good for model classes, but unit testing views and controllers is not possible by definition – they mostly work by connecting several pieces together, while *unit* tests only test single pieces.

You may take a look at [UI tests](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/406/). The important question to ask yourself here is: In the long term, will the energy spent writing UI tests for this case be smaller than the energy possibly spent by testing the case by hand? It’s not a failure to simply write a text document describing some cases to be tested by hand, say before releases. And compared to UI tests, I would say it’s often more effective.

Comment: Views and view controllers can be tested using XCTestCases (unit tests). I have found it very beneficial to unit test view controllers. Admittedly, getting to 100% coverage is nearly impossible, and probably not worth it, but there is definitely value in testing key portions of the code.

Answer (score 0):

you could mock it up

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
}

override func tearDown() {
    super.tearDown()
}

func testTextFieldDidBeginEditingCalled() {

    let sampleTextField = MockTextField(frame: CGRectMake(20, 100, 300, 40))
    sampleTextField.placeholder = "Enter text here"
    sampleTextField.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
    sampleTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
    sampleTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
    sampleTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
    sampleTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    sampleTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing;
    sampleTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center

    sampleTextField.textFieldDidBeginEditing(sampleTextField)

    XCTAssertTrue(sampleTextField.completionInvoked, "should be true")
}

class MockTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var completionInvoked = false

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        print("TextField did begin editing method called")
        completionInvoked = true
    }
}
```